# Laravel pivot table test

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

I've got a test where I check if records in a pivot table are being removed. The test looks like this:

```
/** @test */
public function when_a_relation_is_destroyed_linked_products_will_go_away()
{
    $products = create(Product::class, [], 3)->toArray();
    $relation = create(Relation::class)->syncProducts($products);

    $this->actingAs($this->user)->deleteJson('/relaties/'.$relation->id);

    $this->assertDatabaseMissing('product_has_relations', [
        "product_id" => "1", "relation_id" => "1",
        "product_id" => "2", "relation_id" => "1",
        "product_id" => "3", "relation_id" => "1"
    ]);
}
```

When I test this in my real application the records in the pivot table are removed correctly. But my test keeps failing:

```
Failed asserting that a row in the table [product_has_relations] does not match the attributes {
    "product_id": "3",
    "relation_id": "1"
}.

Found: [
    {
        "product_id": "1",
        "relation_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "product_id": "2",
        "relation_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "product_id": "3",
        "relation_id": "1"
    }
].
```

This is not working aswel:

```
$this->assertDatabaseMissing('product_has_relations', [
    ["product_id" => "1", "relation_id" => "1"],
    ["product_id" => "2", "relation_id" => "1"],
    ["product_id" => "3", "relation_id" => "1"]
]);
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: What is `assertDatabaseMissing`? Never mind, found it https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.php#L27-L44

Comment: First of all alter the "relation" naming its confusing, since all I think is simply relation 1:N or M:N or whatever relation can be when doing CRUD like things. Second of all forget about eloquent managing the delete operation add simple constraint on RDBMS level (It may be the case already). What I would do is `$this->assertEquals(0, $relation->load(['products'])->products->count())` (or something similar, you get the idea).

Comment: @Kyslik thanks. Yes I use constraints on RDBMS level. Your example: ```$this->assertEquals(0, $relation->load(['products'])->products->count())``` would not work because ```relation``` does not exists anymore when It's deleted.

Comment: Do `$this->assertEmpty(Relation:all())` and thats it... I am just hinting, I am not looking for a way to answer your question just to help you along the way, the less code the better.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here `$this->actingAs($this->user)->deleteJson('/relaties/'.$relation->id);`.

Records are not deleted hence the test fails.

Comment: The relation is deleted I've tested that with: ```dd(Relation::all());```.

Comment: @Jamie so you are telling me you see `dd(Relation::all())` produce "empty" and you still want to test concrete array? Just do what you did manually here in the test... `$this->assertEmpty(Relation:all())` one line instead of 4 or 5...